# Preview to a particular page is not working in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I am new asp.net mvc 4.

I have designed one page in which page ,i have kept some button like save,reset and preview.
I have to fill the form like print board number on card,print office fax on card and some other fields also.
when i am clicking on the save button the data it is storing in the database.Reset also working fine.
Preview option ,means i am trying to display all the data in a Modal box .I have referred a site
http://www.paulund.co.uk/how-to-create-a-simple-modal-box-with-jquery .

I want to do when i will click on the preview  option all the data should display in the modal box .Like the above site.

The above site code i have done in dream weaver it is working fine but the same thing i am  trying to do  in asp.net mvc 4  is not working.

Same thing i am trying to do  http://jsfiddle.net/binaynayak/kLfgmzLr/

Will anyone plz help me out to solve this problem.

**Some code of the view page**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Facilities", "OfficialInformation", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
  {
         <table class="grid" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

         <tr class="gridAlternateRow">
                <td>Print board number on the card</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="row">
                        @Html.CheckBox("intPrintBoardNumber")
                    </div>
                </td>

                <td>Print office fax number on the card</td>
                <td colspan="4">
                    <div class="row">
                        @Html.CheckBox("intPrintBuildingFax")
                    </div>
                </td>

            </tr>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btnPrimary">
            <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="btnPrimary">
             <a href="" value="preview" class="btnPrimary"> 
 </table>
```

This form is business card form. My aim is i will fill the form ,before submitting the data into the database i want to preview the form how it will look after printing.Thats my motive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to update your JS file reference in your fiddle:

```
<script src="http://www.paulund.co.uk/playground/demo/jquery_modal_box/jquery.paulund_modal_box.js"></script>
```

I have updated the fiddle you can check it on http://jsfiddle.net/kLfgmzLr/1/

Comment: It is totally related with your html... it will work in .net too.

Comment: thanks for ur cooperation...in dream weaver without this url also it is working (what i have mentioned the url )....but i have tried with this url  given by u, that is also not in working in .net..